# How to remove the value Search from the site search form?

Tags: search

I would like to style the Submit button and use an icon instead of the standard button. I would also like to remove the text/value Search.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: you can use an image as a submit button:

```
<input type="image" src="images/login.jpg" alt="Submit Form" />
```

alternatively you can also place an image an trigger a function that will call

```
form.submit()
```

by using the img tag's `onclick` handler

Comment: Thank you @cerr

That means I would have to customise the core code, correct?

Comment: Answers that are merely links are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange. Then, the question on Stack Overflow is not about Drupal.

Comment: @user19417 Nope, core code should be never touched.

Comment: Thank you @kiamlaluno
Where do I modify the code, if not in the core? Sorry I'm a Drupal begginer..